# Firebase Firestory query where stored timestamp is in the past

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to delete all Documents which have a timestamp (stored in a field) prior to today.

The timestamp is created in the Firestore GUI. The following query doesnt return any docs.

```
collectionRef
.where('timestampFieldName', '<', Date.now())
.get()
```

What exactly is a timestamp, created in the GUI and how to compare it with any date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever passing a date to Firestore, you should pass in an actual `Date` object. `Date.now()` returns a timestamp, which is just a number and not a `Date` object itself. To get the actual `Date` for the same value, use `new Date()`. So:

```
collectionRef
  .where('timestampFieldName', '<', new Date())
  .get()
```