# Firebase query based on date not working in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

My Firestore has a collection of `Events` which includes a Timestamp field, `startDate`. At the moment, there are 4 events: one today, two further in the future and one is dated 1 May 2020.

In my app, I only care about the Events that are *not* in the past. So, I've set up my query as follows:

```
let today = Date()
let todayMidnight = getMidnight(for: today)!
let todayTimeStamp = Timestamp(date: todayMidnight)

activitiesCollection
    .order(by: "startDate")
    .whereField("startDate", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: todayTimeStamp)
activitiesCollection.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
```

I've tried with and without the `order(by:)` clause.

After initially using `todayTimeStamp` in my query, I also tried specifying my date parameter as `today` and `todayMidnight` as per [Frank's answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457751/firebase-firestory-query-where-stored-timestamp-is-in-the-past).

That makes six variations (with/without sorting, three date constants), and in all cases, the query is returning every document in the collection, as if it's ignoring the query altogether.

What am I doing wrong? How can I return only the documents I want instead of all of them?

Comment: Make an event that has a Timestamp of yesterday to see if your whereField clause is not just returning events from today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not storing the query you build, but instead are reading straight from the collection again.

You can either attach the listener straight to the query after you build it:

```
activitiesCollection
    .order(by: "startDate")
    .whereField("startDate", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: todayTimeStamp)
    .addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
```

Or you can keep the query in a variable:

```
let query = activitiesCollection
    .order(by: "startDate")
    .whereField("startDate", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: todayTimeStamp)
query.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
```

Comment: Oh, God. Is it really that simple? I feel so embarrassed. I think I had that before but I was trying to "simplify my code" and combine the query definition with the listeners, not realizing it would have that effect. I'll try it right away. (And I knew you would be the one to set me straight.....)

Comment: Worked perfectly, as you said. "100 Points for Hufflepuff!"